# Refreshing an infragistics webdatatree

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I have an .aspx page with a WebDataTree control, a WebHierarchicalDataSource control (configured with 2 SqlDataSource controls), and a WebUpload control.

It's a simple setup, user uploads a file, which executes some code-behind that updates the database, which should then refresh the WebDataTree.  The tree is indeed initially populated with existing data.  And Uploading new files should refresh that list.

The database does get updated with new file information, and If I force a page refresh the tree does get repopulated.  But I'd like the WebDataTree to repopulate once a file is uploaded, which I normally do by calling the control's DataBind() on post back, in this case WedDataTree1.DataBind() during the WebUpload1_UploadFinished() event.

But this does not refresh the WebDataTree control. Am I missing something?  Is this not the way to refresh the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UploadFinished even isn't a request for the page so there is no page sent back to the client.  You should handle the [client side fileUploaded](http://help.infragistics.com/doc/ASPNET/Current/CLR4.0/?page=WebUpload_Using_Client_Side_Events.html) event and trigger the refresh of the WebDataTree from the client.  For this you would need to trigger a post back from code and rebind the tree on the server.  If you wanted to avoid doing a post back manually you could look into using the [Ignite UI tree](http://igniteui.com/tree/overview) and make a call to the server just to get the updated data.

Comment: clearly I have more to learn about the ig controls.  Thanks for putting me on the right path. Regarding the Ignite UI Tree to obtain the data, would that be a call to igTree("databind") ?

Comment: That will do data binding.  If you are binding to the same data source you had before that may be sufficient and if you are changing the data source you may need to also set the dataSource.

Comment: yes same datasource, just need to rebind to build the tree so that it shows the just uploaded file in the tree.  However, I could find a way to make the Ignite UI work with a `WebHierarchicalDataSource` And I'm way behind as it is so couldn't afford more time to research it so instead I opted to handle the client side `_FileUploaded` event with a call to `__doPostBack('<WebDataTree's Update Panel>', '')` and that did the trick for me.  Again, thanks for the help

Comment: If you use the Ignite UI tree, you would want to get the data on the client from a service or a page method if using ASP.NET Web Forms.  For the data you would just need to send JSON data to the client and then set the dataSource like this example is doing: http://www.igniteui.com/tree/json-binding